# Vue.js - data value does not set from prop

Tags: vue.js

**What do I have**: two components, parent and child.

Parent

```
<UserName :name=user.name></UserName>
...
components: {UserName},
    data() {
      return {
        user: {
          name: '',
          ...
        }
      }
    },
    created() {
      this.fetchUser()
      console.log(this.user) //<- object as it is expected
    },
    methods: {
      fetchUser() {
        let that = this
        axios.get(//...)
          .then(response => {
            for (let key in response.data) {
              that.user[key] = response.data[key]
            }
          })
        console.log(that.user) //<- object as it is expected
      }
    }
```

Child

```
<h3 v-if="!editing" @click="edit">{{ usersName }}</h3>
<div v-if="editing">
    <div>
        <input type="text" v-model="usersName">
    </div>
</div>
...
props: {
  name: {
    type: String,
    default: ''
  },
},
data() {
  return {
    editing: false,
    usersName: this.name,
    ...
  }
},
```

**Problem**: even when `name` prop is set at child, `usersName` data value is empty. I've inspected Vue debug extension - same problem.

**What have I tried so far** (nothing helped):

1) `props: ['name']`

2)

```
props: {
  name: {
    type: String
  },
},
```

3) `usersName: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.name))`

4) `<UserName :name="this.user.name"></UserName>`

P. S. when I pass static value from parent to child

```
<UserName :name="'just a string'"></UserName>
```

`usersName` is set correctly.

---

I've also tried to change `name` prop to some `foobar`. I guessed `name` might conflict with component `name` exactly. But it also didn't helped.

Comment: `<UserName :name="user.name"></UserName>` Did you miss the quote around `user.name` when pass the prop to child?

Comment: @Psidom hmm, I used to make work other similar components without quotes. By the way, I've tried wwith qoutes and without - same result.

Comment: what if you `console.log` `that.user` in `fetchUser` after updating it with the `for` loop? Did you see updated `user`?

Comment: @Psidom yes, I've updated the question with `console.log()` also

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`user.name` is initially empty, and later gets a value from an axios call. `usersName` is initialized from the prop when it is created. The value it gets is the initial, empty value. When `user.name` changes, that doesn't affect the already-initialized `data` item in the child.

You might want to use the [`.sync` modifier](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#sync-Modifier) along with a [settable computed](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#sync-Modifier), or you might want to put in a [`watch`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers) to propagate changes from the prop into the child. Which behavior you want is not clear.

Here's an example using `.sync`

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    user: {
      name: ''
    }
  },
  methods: {
    fetchUser() {
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.user.name = 'Slartibartfast'
      }, 800);
    }
  },
  created() {
    this.fetchUser();
  },
  components: {
    userName: {
      template: '#user-name-template',
      props: {
        name: {
          type: String,
          default: ''
        }
      },
      computed: {
        usersName: {
          get() { return this.name; },
          set(value) { this.$emit('update:name', value); }
        }
      },
      data() {
        return {
          editing: false
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@latest/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  {{user.name}}
  <user-name :name.sync=user.name></user-name>
</div>

<template id="user-name-template">
    <div>
        <input type="text" v-model="usersName">
    </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 2):

should be passed like this...
`<UserName :name="user.name"></UserName>`

if data property is still not being set, in `mounted` hook you could set the name property.

```
mounted() {
    this.usersName = this.name
}
```

if this doesn't work then your prop is not being passed correctly.

sidenote: I typically `console.log` within the mounted hook to test such things.

Comment: if you console log the prop within the mounted hook and still nothing, then you know for sure the issue is the way it's being passed and is irrelevant to the child.